# Modifying plain PDF to introduce interactive elements

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I have a 70 page PDF that I would like to modify to make elements interactive. For instance I would like to intruduce a contents page that links to other pages and links within the rest of the document. As InDesign doesn't seem to allow the opening of PDF's whats the best option?

Comment: There is a script for opening Multi-Page-PDFs in InDesign, check out [Zanelli Releases MultiPageImporter for Importing both PDF and INDD Files](http://indesignsecrets.com/zanelli-releases-multipageimporter-for-importing-both-pdf-and-indd-files.php).

Comment: Acrobat DC can't do this?

Comment: That's something you could do in Acrobat since about version 2…

Comment: @AndrewH that worked perfectly. Thanks very much for the heads up!